# Neo4j cache and performance

Tags: performance, caching, neo4j

I'm testing a query in neo4j and I see that when I clear the cache . Neo4j takes more time to load . which mean performances are dicreasing .
Why  is this happening 
I don't know now whether to clear the cache for each query ? or should I just test without clearing the cache

Comment: How do you clear the cache ?

Comment: a) that's exactly how you would expect a cache to behave: make queries faster when it is filled.  b) why is this tagged "browser-cache"? What cache are you talking about exactly?

Comment: @logisima I clear the cache from the browser  (clear local data )

Comment: @Thilo that was just an error I mean caching

Comment: Browser doesn't cache any (query) data from the server.

Comment: @logisima then how do we clear it ?

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j browser doesn't cache any data from a query.
So clearing your browser cache has no incidence on the query execution time.

Perhaps the browser is creating a new connection to the database, makes some computations (like colors for nodes for example), etc.

To see the query execution time, on the query panel, select the `row` result, and take a look at the bottom. You should see something like that : `Started streaming 50 records after 2 ms and completed after 12 ms.` The `2 ms` is your query execution time.

If you want to optimize / see the performance of a query, I recommend you to use the `EXPLAIN` and `PROFILE`.

FYI, Neo4j has two caches :

- the one for the data -> pagecache. Neo4j put in RAM its data files, so to access them is fast
- the one for query execution plan -> if you are using parameterised queries, Neo4j doesn't re-computing the query plan if it already has it

Cheers

Comment: For the execution time , that's exactly where I retrieve it .So If I got you right, I don't need to delete the cache ? the browser  local  cache does not affect the performance . I just repeat the query without deleting anything . ?

Comment: Don't delete your browser cache, just test your query